# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'count')

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-admin

I am new to react-admin and am having issues with wiring up a data provider (ra-data-graphql-simple) with my GraphQL API. I'm getting the following error in a little red box at the bottom of the page:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'count')

In Google Chrome's dev tools on the Network tab I do see correct results being returned but the `total` is null:

[image]

This is how I am wiring up the `Admin`, `Resource`, and `buildGraphQLProvider`:

```
const App = () => {
    const [dataProvider, setDataProvider] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        buildGraphQLProvider({ clientOptions: { uri: 'http://localhost:4000' } })
            .then(graphQlDataProvider => setDataProvider(() => graphQlDataProvider));
    }, []);

    if (!dataProvider)
        return <div>Loading</div>

    return (
        <Admin dataProvider= { dataProvider } >
          <Resource name="FacilityFunction" list={ FunctionList } />
      </Admin>
    );
}
```

Here is my `FunctionList` component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, BooleanField } from 'react-admin'

export const FunctionList = (props) => {
    return <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id"></TextField>
            <TextField source="name"></TextField>
            <TextField source="code"></TextField>
            <BooleanField source="isActive"></BooleanField>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
};
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "ra-data-graphql-simple": "^4.0.3",
    "react": "18.1",
    "react-admin": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "18.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by defining a query (on the graphql server side) like what was shown here: [apollo graphql schema react-admin beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627234/apollo-graphql-schema-react-admin-beginner).

@react-admin it would be **extremely** helpful to build out an entire example with both the graphql server requirements and each `list`, `edit`, `create`, and `show` components that you have started here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql-simple

The way react-admin expects the graphql schema is very opinionated and needs to be explained up-front and very clearly.